# How sign() method of the digital signature combines the (r,s) values in to array bytes to return the calling body

Tags: java, cryptography

I am implementing the Elliptic curve Digital signature Algorithm(ECDA) without reusing the standard implemented one using java programing.my program is something like this.

```
     public BigInteger[] sign(){

    // signature generation here

        rs[0] = r;
         rs[1] = s;
        return rs;
      }
```

but  i want it to return byte array which is like this  as in the standard algorithm implemented.

```
    public byte[] sign()
    {      
           // my signature generation here already done
            rs[0] = r;
            rs[1] = s;   
          // help me here what shall i do instead of returning array of two BigIntegers
    }
```

How sign() method of the digital signature  combines the (r,s)  values in to array bytes to return the calling body. At calling body i have to the get (r,s) pair back in  order to verify my signature.

```
         // something like this
            public boolean verify(byte[] sigbyte )
              {

                 rArr =  // help me here
                 sArr = // help me here
                r =new BigInteger(rArr);
                s = new BigInteger(sArr);

               // i have already done signature verification here

               }
```

Comment: Why do you want it as a byte[] ? According to FIPS 186-3 section C.2.1 it is supposed to be a string (bit-string) of "0"s and "1"s. And since it is one byte array, the extra leading zeros of the bytes of s would be hard to get rid of when converting the byte[] into a string. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Normally only octets are used. You would need to remove or append 00h octet values at the left hand size, you are correct in that. You will have to copy the byte array to another one. Difficult? Not really. A nuissance, hard to get right and waste of memory? Certainly.

Answer (score 3):

FIPS 186-3 does not specify how to serialize an ECDSA signature as a bytearray.

All APIs and protocols I know of use one of two different standard ways:

1) Zero-pad r and s so they are the length of n (the order of G) and concatenate them:

```
byte[] rArr = toUnsignedByteArray(r);
byte[] sArr = toUnsignedByteArray(s);
int nLength = (n.bitLength()+7)/8;
byte[] res = new byte[2*nLength];
System.arraycopy(rArr, 0, res, nLength - rArr.length, rArr.length);
System.arraycopy(sArr, 0, res, 2* nLength - sArr.length, nLength);
```

`toUnsignedByteArray` is something like:

```
byte[] toUnsignedByteArray(BigInteger bi){
  byte[] ba = bi.toByteArray();
  if(ba[0] != 0){
    return ba;
  }
  else
  {
    byte[] ba2 = new byte[ba.length - 1];
    System.arraycopy(ba, 1, ba2, 0, ba.length - 1);
    return ba2;
  }
}
```

2) Use the DER-encoding of the following ASN.1 structure:

```
ECDSASignature ::= SEQUENCE {
    r   INTEGER,
    s   INTEGER
}
```

Assuming n is at most 487 bit (if you need to support larger keys, the length-encoding gets somewhat more complex):

```
byte[] rArr = r.toByteArray();
byte[] sArr = s.toByteArray();
byte[] res = new byte[6 + rArr.length + sArr.length];
res[0] = 0x30;
res[1] = 4 + rArr.length + sArr.length;
res[2] = 0x02;
res[3] = rArr.length;
System.arraycopy(rArr, 0, res, 4, rArr.length);
res[4+rArr.length] = 0x02;
res[5+rArr.length] = sArr.length;
System.arraycopy(sArr, 0, res, 6+rArr.length, sArr.length);
```

To decode do something like this (this is very basic, non-error-resistant decoding):

```
if(enc[0]!=0x30) return false; // bad encoding
if(enc[1]&0x80!=0) return false; // unsupported length encoding
if(enc[2]!=0x02) return false; // bad encoding
if(enc[3]&0x80!=0) return false; // unsupported length encoding
int rLength = enc[3];
byte[] rArr = new byte[rLength];
System.arraycopy(enc, 4, rArr, 0, rLength);
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(rArr);
if(enc[4+rLength]!=0x02) return false; // bad encoding
if(enc[5+rLength]&0x80!=0) return false; // unsupported length encoding
int sLength = enc[5+rLength];
byte[] sArr = new byte[sLength];
System.arraycopy(enc, 6+rLength, sArr, 0, sLength);
BigInteger s = new BigInteger(sArr);
```

The second encoding is used by the Java Security Architecture.

Comment: I want to recover the original  (r,s) pair in my signature verification. in the first code it is easy to recover the (r,s) as bigIntegers. but second one i found hard can add some ideas or codes

Comment: It's wrong though, ASN.1 integers are signed just like Java integers. Basically, you don't need any conversion. A single I2OS (integer to octet string) function would be better as well, if only for memory usage. Could you amend so I can +1

Comment: @owlstead: Converted the ASN.1-encoding back to complement-2 (sorry, been too long since I handcoded ASN.1). Could you expand the second comment, I am not sure I can see the problem.

Comment: Hmm, that might be alright on second thought. Thanks for ammending the ASN.1 part. It's a bit -uh- direct way of encoding ASN.1, but it may suffice.

Comment: @owlstead: I don't really think it would be correct to take a dependency on a ASN.1-encoder/-parser for such a little structure and at such a low-level in the structure. I am quite sure I did something not very different from this the last time I implemented ECDSA (which is admittedly >5 years ago). I would probably use a ByteArrayAppender and put some more work into the length-encodings, but I don't think much more would be appropriate at this level. You don't usually see a ASN.1 engine used for the DigestInfo inside PKCS#1 v1.5 either.

Comment: DigestInfo is a fully static structure (up to the digest of course), even specified in the standard. If you are using X9.62 compatible signatures it is likely that the key itself will have to be encoded using ASN.1 too, so in that case an ASN.1 library (or at least DER encoding, often mistaken) would become useful. But I agree that in this case it will suffice, as indicated in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The FIPS 186-3 document specifies the algorithm but does not talk about how to use the algorithm in higher-level protocols. The standard that I am most familiar with for encoding the signature into a byte array is [RFC 3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279), specifically section 2.2.2. This is probably the encoding method used by the default Oracle providers.

Comment: It is, it's based on ANSI X9.62/63, which this RFC is compliant to (as far as I can see). The other method of representation often used it two big endian integers with the same size as the order as Rasmus indicated.